# Best Way to Parallelize OpenCV cvCanny with OpenMP

Tags: opencv, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize openCV functions like **cvCanny**, **cvSmooth** and **cvThreshold** and I wonder which is the best way to do it using OpenMP.

Someone knows how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you don't do that in *your own* code.

instead, recompile the opencv *library code* so that it uses OpenMP (enable WITH_OPENMP in cmake-gui or cmake)

(also, please avoid the outdated c-api, they stopped developing it already 5 years ago, use cv::Canny, cv::blur and cv::threshold instead)

Comment: I've compiled openCV with OpenMP already. How to enable it on my code? Does setNumThreads() do it for me automatically? Thanks

Comment: If we are calling c function in opencv, will it internally calls its corresponding c++ functions.